# How to undervolt a laptop CPU

Tags: windows, cpu, hardware-acceleration

I have a Dell Inspiron 7559 laptop and it's processor is core i7-6700HQ.

I have read some articles about undervolting the CPU and its benefit and I want to do it for my laptop.

I have some questions:

1. Is undervolting really safe?
2. Has anyone done undervolting for me specific laptop or processor?
3. How do I go about undervolting my processor?
4. Why do CPU producers give the processor more voltage than they need?

Comment: _"Why CPU producers give processor more voltage than they need?"_ - they don't.

Comment: then why there is the idea of undervolting?

Comment: There's some variance in chip quality. Some chips require higher voltage to remain stable, some work well with lower voltage. Manufacturers use lowest voltage that guarentees stable operation of all chips. Few chips will work perfectly fine with lower voltage, some will work mostly OK but will crash in 1% of cases, some will be unstable or totally unusable. It doesn't make sense for CPU manufacturers to thoroughly test and rate every single, although I've seen some mobile CPUs reporting their [bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_binning).

Comment: @gronostaj: It's more complicated than that: Not all the cores of a CPU are of the same quality, so the chip controller tries to achieve the lowest voltage possible in view of the workload which will achieve homogeneous speed of all cores. So the voltage is different for *each core*.

Answer (score 0):

You are in error.

Modern CPUs reduce voltage to the minimum necessary to carry out their tasks.
Modern OS park cores that are not required for the current workload.

In short, manufacturers and OS developers are currently making a large effort to
reduce electricity usage, in order to prolong the lifetime of battery charges on laptops.

Comment: then why there is the idea of undervolting?

Comment: Because people like to tweak things.

Comment: In Windows you can reduce the percentage of the CPU that it's allowed to use and achieve the same: slower computer but longer battery time. But the OS and hardware really do a good enough job, and it's dynamic, while any change you do will be static in nature.